# How do you rotate a camera photo?

Tags: 7.5, camera, pictures

I just took a picture with the phone's camera, but it's on its side (or upside down) compared to my perspective when I took it.

How can I rotate or flip the picture so it's the right side up? [Microsoft says Windows Phone 8.0 can do this on its own](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/photos/take-edit-and-share-photos-and-videos), but my phone runs 7.5.

Comment: Try some of the photo apps, otherwise you can do this on your PC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built in camera application does not let you rotate, but there are a few good applications that do it for you.

[Fotoroom](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/acad1eed-3149-4b6c-bc4b-8567f409e3e0) is an excellent app that lets you do quick edits to a photo, and best of all it is free!

Comment: BTW The app is called Fhotoroom, note the 'h'.